# Non-printable characters in http request message body

Tags: php, validation, http-headers

Let's say someone (an attacker) sends a http request where a http message body contains a string **asdf** with a **BACKSPACE** character (\x08).

How PHP sees this request? Is it **asd** or **asdf\x08**?

Should I always test and remove non-printable characters when validating user input from html forms?

Comment: the best practice is to test all user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to my question: PHP strings are just array of bytes without any knowledge of how these bytes should be converted to characters. So if a user sends a backspace character or other control characters by POST method, all the bytes of these control characters are preserved. These characters may pose a security threat when the input string is being sent to an application that tries to interpret the characters.